# how can stop only thread but program should keep running in python

Tags: python, multithreading

```
import time
import threading

class Check(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        self.stopped = False
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        i = 0
        while not self.stopped:
            time.sleep(1)
            i = i + 1
            print(i)
            if(i==5):
                self.stopped = True

inst = Check()
inst.start()
```

Comment: You need to format your code correctly so that it shows up right on StackOverflow.  Select the code block and click on the curly brackets (`{}`) and it will scoot it over by 4 spaces so that it appears correctly.  Look at the preview below the edit panel to see the final result.

Comment: Code only questions are not welcome here... You should read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up your own mechanism for stopping a thread--Python doesn't have a built-in way to do it.  This is actually a common problem among many languages, not just Python.

```
import time
import threading

class Check(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        # An event can be useful here, though a simple boolean works too since
        # assignment is atomic in Python.
        self.stop_event = threading.Event()

    def run(self):
        i = 0
        while not self.stop_event.is_set():
            time.sleep(1)
            i = i + 1
            print(i)
            if(i==5):
                self.stopped = True

    def stop(self):
        # Tell the thread to stop...
        self.stop_event.set()
        # Wait for the thread to stop
        self.join()

inst = Check()
inst.start()

# Do stuff...
time.sleep(1)

inst.stop()

# Thread has stopped, but the main thread is still running...
print("I'm still here!")
```

Here I use an event to signal whether or not the thread should stop.  We add a stop method to signal the event and then wait for the thread to finish processing before continuing.  This is very simplistic, but hopefully it gives you the idea of the kind of strategy you can take.  It gets much more complicated if you want to handle error conditions like being informed if an error occurred in the `run()` method or if the body of the `run()` method is taking too long, etc.